# Weak Induction Proof - Variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Can someone help me understand this problem? Why is it necessary in step 2 to set n=m?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqWWb.jpg

Comment: It's not. I reckon this is a case where the writer saved up on words where more words would have done a better job. As I understand it, what is meant here is the *inductive step*: "suppose $C_m = 3^{2^m}$. Let's show that $C_{m+1} = 3^{2^{m+1}}$" (which is step 3).

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They want to show that if the statement is true for $n=m$ then it is also true for $n=m+1$

Some authors use if true for $k$ then it is true for $k+1$

Some authors use if it is true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$

It is a matter of taste and they are all equivalent.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm used to seeing it in the form: if it is true for k, then it is true for k + 1. But in this case I'm staying consistent with the variable. I guess this example just threw me off

Comment: It is a matter of taste.